# Bash Ctrl-A Returns to Start of Line but Doesn't Display Properly

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

When I ssh into a Linux server from bash Terminal, I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to return to the start of line properly, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to go to end of line and everything works fine.

When I use bash locally on my Mac, when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it logically goes back to the start of the line, but doesn't display the cursor in the correct place.  It displays the cursor 7 or so characters off and doesn't update the line text correct.

**Example**

```
find . -name "hello.cpp"
```

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>!**

```
find . -name "hello.cpp"
       ^~~ cursor shows here ????
```

**Insert "this is a test" (just to show)**

Displays:

```
find . this is a test -name "hello.cpp"
                      ^~~ cursor is still here ???
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~^ text inserted here ???
^~~~~~^ unchanged for some reason
```

**Command executed**

```
this is a test find . -name "hello.cpp"
```

I use the same

```
PS1=\n \e[1;95m \u@\h \e[0;32m\w \e[1;30m $(__git_ps1 " (%s)" ) \n \e[1;95m \@ \n $ \e[0;30m
```

as I do on Linux.

**Version Info**

- bash version: 3.2.57(1)
- terminal version: 2.6.1 (361.1)
- OS X El Capitan, 10.11.5

Comment: Actually the reason seems to be the opposite you need \[ \] to enclose the colour shift codes as per the article quoted there http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/

Comment: Adding `\[` and `\]` around the colors solved the problem.  It's actually the inverse of the other problem, which I'd recommend changing the subject line for as this is a more general issue than just for "emacs style".  Do you want me to mark as duplicate even though they're inversed?  I think this subject would make it easier to find.

Comment: Currently it is not a duplicate but I suspect a question could be written using the other answer to produce a common question

Comment: @Mark I converted your comment to an answer. Questions should have answers. If you create your own answer (you can copy the one I added if you want) then I will delete mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `\[` and `\]` around the colour codes to enable bash to calculate the line length correctly. Something like this:

```
PS1=\n \[\e[1;95m\] \u@\h \[\e[0;32m\]\w \[\e[1;30m\] $(__git_ps1 " (%s)" ) \n \[\e[1;95m\] \@ \n $ \[\e[0;30m\]
```

(This answer is taken from @Mark's comment on the question.)

This fix works for other commands like Ctrl-W