# ctrl + w not deleting until the beginning of line in bash shell

Tags: terminal, bash, sonoma

the `ctrl + w` shortcut does not delete words until the beginning of the line, in bash shell; it gets stuck few characters before
(`ctrl + c` would bring me to a normal new line)

this is something weird I never saw before (maybe related to new macos 14 ?)

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I can see, this seems the same issue as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611464/why-is-my-mac-terminal-acting-buggy-when-i-use-the-up-arrow-key

so, the solution is to fix the `PS1` variable

Comment: You should flag as a duplicate rather than post a link-only answer.

Comment: @barmar Duplicates don’t work across SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

Does this answer your question?

[Bash Ctrl-A Returns to Start of Line but Doesn't Display Properly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241735/bash-ctrl-a-returns-to-start-of-line-but-doesnt-display-properly?rq=1)

If your PS1 has unprintable characters in it, such as color codes, you need to explicitly escape them or `bash` will think they consume space on the line.

Comment: Excellent analysis. I was struggling to understand this but the link fills in all the back story.